# How many $3$-digit numbers can be formed so that the sum of two digits will be equal to the third digit?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many $3$-digit numbers can be formed so that the sum of two digits will be equal to the third digit?

I am confused in this question whether to take first 2 digits sum or any digit sum such that it is equal to 3rd digit.

For example, some combinations 112 can be written into 3 ways  112 112 121 
such that in the last

Example 3rd number and first number sum = 2 (middle number).

Also, is there any better approach towards this problem rather than counting and arranging the 3 digit number?

Comment: Your confusion is completely reasonable, the problem as quoted is not well-stated and there are at least two reasonable interpretations.

Comment: Have you reproduced the question *exactly* ? "sum of the 2 digits" is not even proper English.

Comment: @trueblueanil reproduced the correct english form of the question.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes What to do i think  Calculate and See the options side by side

Comment: @justintakro What language was the question originally in?  Translations are notorious for leaving behind implicit meaning.

Comment: @user46944 English

Comment: If you have *reproduced*, (not *changed*) to correct English form, I would interpret it as the sum of any 2 digits is equal to the third.

Comment: @trueblueanil yes

Comment: Now that the problem has been edited, the ambiguity has disappeared.

Comment: I would interpret it any 3-digit number where to sum of one pair of the three digits is equal to the third remaining digit.  What I'd do for simplicity case as calculate how many 0 < a < b;  a+b=c <10; multiply that number by 6.  Then calculate 0 < a; 2a = c < 10 and multiply that number by 3.  And then count the 9 of  0=a < b = c and multiply by 2.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the problem means that the sum of any two digits equals the third.

To start, let's find out how many 3 digit numbers have the last digit as the sum of the first two digits:

Here, the first digit cannot be $0$ or $9$.  It can't be $9$ because the sum of $9$ and any digit is a two digit number If the first digit is $1$ then second number can be any digit from $0$ to $8$.  So nine possibilities.  If the first digit is $2$ then the possibities for the second digit is $0$ through $7$.

So, the number of three digit numbers whose first two digits add up to the third is: $9+8+\cdots +1$.

Now, the total of all numbers in which the sum any two digits is 3 times the previous answer because the sum digit could be the first, second or third digit.

Comment: So,according to you Ans is 135

Comment: Yes.  That's what I get.

Comment: Why can't the first digit be 9? 909 has as last digit the sum of the other digits.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

To write the problem in somewhat mathematical terms, we have three digits $d_1 \in \{1, \dots, 9\}$, $d_2,d_3 \in \{0, 1, \dots, 9\}$ that form a $3$-digit number 
$$x = d_1 \cdot 10^2 + d_2 \cdot 10 + d_3$$
Now, we want to find all possible values of $x$ such that at least one of the following holds:

- $d_1 + d_2 = d_3$,
- $d_1 + d_3 = d_2$,
- $d_2 + d_3 = d_1$

Let's start with the first condition. We may pick $d_1$ freely, which gives us $9$ options. However, since $d_3 \in \{0, 1, \dots, 9\}$, we must always choose $d_2 \in \{0, \dots, 9-d_1\}$. Hence:
$$\# \{ x \mid d_1 + d_2 = d_3\} = \sum_{d_i = 1}^{9}(10-d_i) = 45$$
The same reasoning holds for the second condition:
$$\# \{ x \mid d_1 + d_3 = d_2\} = \sum_{d_i = 1}^{9}(10-d_i) = 45$$
However, the last condition is different! We pick $d_2$ freely which gives us $10$ options, and we must choose $d_3 \in \{0, \dots, 9-d_2\}$. However, we also have to exclude one case: $d_2 = d_3 = 0$, because then $d_1$ would also be $0$. Hence:
$$\# \{ x \mid d_2 + d_3 = d_1\} = \sum_{d_i = 0}^{9}(10-d_i)-1 = 54$$
We now have $45 + 45 + 54 = 144$ numbers $x$ such that either of the conditions hold. However, some numbers are counted twice. It is easy to see that a number is counted twice if and only if $d_i = d_j$ and $d_k = 0$ for $i,j,k$ being some permutation of $1,2,3$. Since $d_1 \neq 0$, the multiples we need to discard are those of the form $d_2 = 0$ or $d_3 = 0$. There are $9$ of each ($d0d$ and $dd0$ with $d = 1, \dots, 9$), so we remove $18$ multiples. There is no number for which all $3$ conditions hold, since that would require $d_1 = d_2 = d_3 = 0$.

The solution is then:
$$\#\{x\} = 144- 18 = 126.$$

Comment: You might mention that there are no solutions where all three conditions hold, as you would have to add those back (priciple of inclusion and exclusion)

Comment: @ChristianSievers You're right, I've added that.

Comment: @DPoole Only the condition $d_1 + d_2 = d_3$ holds for that one.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is 126.

Where X is first digit (1 through to 9) and y is number of digits use equation below and add answers:

```
             y=  2(9-X) + ( 10-(9-X))
```

eg X=1  2(9-1) + ( 10 - (9-1)) =18
Then working through remaining first digits:   X=2 y=17, X=3 y=16......X=9 y=10
Sum of the Y values is 126

Answer (score 1):

One answer says $126$, the other $135$. Which one is correct?

Brute-forcing in [Haskell](http://tryhaskell.org),

```
λ filter (\(a,b,c)->(a+b==c || a+c==b || b+c==a)) [ (x2,x1,x0) | x0 <- [0..9], x1 <- [0..9], x2 <- [1..9] ]
[(1,1,0),(2,2,0),(3,3,0),(4,4,0),(5,5,0),(6,6,0),(7,7,0),(8,8,0),(9,9,0),(1,0,1),(2,1,1),(1,2,1),(3,2,1),(2,3,1),(4,3,1),(3,4,1),(5,4,1),(4,5,1),(6,5,1),(5,6,1),(7,6,1),(6,7,1),(8,7,1),(7,8,1),(9,8,1),(8,9,1),(2,0,2),(1,1,2),(3,1,2),(4,2,2),(1,3,2),(5,3,2),(2,4,2),(6,4,2),(3,5,2),(7,5,2),(4,6,2),(8,6,2),(5,7,2),(9,7,2),(6,8,2),(7,9,2),(3,0,3),(2,1,3),(4,1,3),(1,2,3),(5,2,3),(6,3,3),(1,4,3),(7,4,3),(2,5,3),(8,5,3),(3,6,3),(9,6,3),(4,7,3),(5,8,3),(6,9,3),(4,0,4),(3,1,4),(5,1,4),(2,2,4),(6,2,4),(1,3,4),(7,3,4),(8,4,4),(1,5,4),(9,5,4),(2,6,4),(3,7,4),(4,8,4),(5,9,4),(5,0,5),(4,1,5),(6,1,5),(3,2,5),(7,2,5),(2,3,5),(8,3,5),(1,4,5),(9,4,5),(1,6,5),(2,7,5),(3,8,5),(4,9,5),(6,0,6),(5,1,6),(7,1,6),(4,2,6),(8,2,6),(3,3,6),(9,3,6),(2,4,6),(1,5,6),(1,7,6),(2,8,6),(3,9,6),(7,0,7),(6,1,7),(8,1,7),(5,2,7),(9,2,7),(4,3,7),(3,4,7),(2,5,7),(1,6,7),(1,8,7),(2,9,7),(8,0,8),(7,1,8),(9,1,8),(6,2,8),(5,3,8),(4,4,8),(3,5,8),(2,6,8),(1,7,8),(1,9,8),(9,0,9),(8,1,9),(7,2,9),(6,3,9),(5,4,9),(4,5,9),(3,6,9),(2,7,9),(1,8,9)]

λ length $ filter (\(a,b,c)->(a+b==c || a+c==b || b+c==a)) [ (x2,x1,x0) | x0 <- [0..9], x1 <- [0..9], x2 <- [1..9] ]
126
```

If $x_2 = 0$ is allowed, then

```
λ filter (\(a,b,c)->(a+b==c || a+c==b || b+c==a)) [ (x2,x1,x0) | x0 <- [0..9], x1 <- [0..9], x2 <- [0..9] ]
[(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(2,2,0),(3,3,0),(4,4,0),(5,5,0),(6,6,0),(7,7,0),(8,8,0),(9,9,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(2,1,1),(1,2,1),(3,2,1),(2,3,1),(4,3,1),(3,4,1),(5,4,1),(4,5,1),(6,5,1),(5,6,1),(7,6,1),(6,7,1),(8,7,1),(7,8,1),(9,8,1),(8,9,1),(2,0,2),(1,1,2),(3,1,2),(0,2,2),(4,2,2),(1,3,2),(5,3,2),(2,4,2),(6,4,2),(3,5,2),(7,5,2),(4,6,2),(8,6,2),(5,7,2),(9,7,2),(6,8,2),(7,9,2),(3,0,3),(2,1,3),(4,1,3),(1,2,3),(5,2,3),(0,3,3),(6,3,3),(1,4,3),(7,4,3),(2,5,3),(8,5,3),(3,6,3),(9,6,3),(4,7,3),(5,8,3),(6,9,3),(4,0,4),(3,1,4),(5,1,4),(2,2,4),(6,2,4),(1,3,4),(7,3,4),(0,4,4),(8,4,4),(1,5,4),(9,5,4),(2,6,4),(3,7,4),(4,8,4),(5,9,4),(5,0,5),(4,1,5),(6,1,5),(3,2,5),(7,2,5),(2,3,5),(8,3,5),(1,4,5),(9,4,5),(0,5,5),(1,6,5),(2,7,5),(3,8,5),(4,9,5),(6,0,6),(5,1,6),(7,1,6),(4,2,6),(8,2,6),(3,3,6),(9,3,6),(2,4,6),(1,5,6),(0,6,6),(1,7,6),(2,8,6),(3,9,6),(7,0,7),(6,1,7),(8,1,7),(5,2,7),(9,2,7),(4,3,7),(3,4,7),(2,5,7),(1,6,7),(0,7,7),(1,8,7),(2,9,7),(8,0,8),(7,1,8),(9,1,8),(6,2,8),(5,3,8),(4,4,8),(3,5,8),(2,6,8),(1,7,8),(0,8,8),(1,9,8),(9,0,9),(8,1,9)

λ length $ filter (\(a,b,c)->(a+b==c || a+c==b || b+c==a)) [ (x2,x1,x0) | x0 <- [0..9], x1 <- [0..9], x2 <- [0..9] ]
136
```

Even if we remove $000$ from the list, which would give $135$ numbers, $011$ is **not** a $3$-digit number.

Comment: You're right, the answer is indeed $126$. There are $45$ numbers such that $d_1 + d_2 = d_3$, as the accepted answer says, but one cannot simply multiply this by $3$ and claim to have the answer, because the problem is not symmetric due to $d_1 \neq 0$.

We may calculate that there are also $45$ numbers such that $d_1 + d_3 = d_2$, but there are $54 = 45 + 9$ numbers such that $d_2 + d_3 = d_1$.

This would lead to $45 + 45 + 54 = 144$. However, some numbers are counted multiple times: those of the form $dd0$ and $d0d$. There are $18$ such numbers, so the solution is $144-18 = 126$.

Comment: @SteamyRoot  You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Since, it's not given whether the repetition of digits is allowed or not so I'm solving this by considering repetition to be allowed

**The possible combinations can be formed by starting with each of the digits from 1 to 9 so that their sum with the other digit (second digit) is equal to the third digit**

**(1)** Starting with digit 1, possible combinations are:
{101,112,123,134,145,156,167,178,189} i.e total number of combinations formed by starting with the digit 1 are 9

**(2)** Starting with digit 2, possible combinations are:
$\{202,213,224,235,246,257,268,279\}$ i.e total number of combinations formed by starting with the digit 2 are 8

Proceeding in the same way, we have the total number of combinations formed by starting with the digits $3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ are $7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1$ respectively.

Therefore, the total number of such combinations $= 9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1$
$=       45$

Hence, the total number of 3-digit numbers can be formed so that the sum of two digits will be equal to the third digit is 45.